# object extends trait v.s class extends trait

Tags: scala

What is the benefit we declare `object Nil` to extends `TweetList`?
why not still use `class Nil`?

```
trait TweetList {
  def head: Tweet
  def tail: TweetList
  def isEmpty: Boolean
  def foreach(f: Tweet => Unit): Unit =
    if (!isEmpty) {
      f(head)
      tail.foreach(f)
    }
}

object Nil extends TweetList {
  def head = throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException("head of EmptyList")
  def tail = throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException("tail of EmptyList")
  def isEmpty = true
}

class Cons(val head: Tweet, val tail: TweetList) extends TweetList {
  def isEmpty = false
}
```

Comment: Memory efficiency. There's no point in creating multiple instances from a `class Nil` if they are all the same and serve the same purpose. As an `object` there is only one instance and that is all that is needed.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between an **object** and a **class** and thus you are asking why one would use an **object** here? Or you don't know the difference between both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's [a link](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/singleton-objects.html.html) for how to use singleton class.

Above comments also mentioned about it, but I explain it again.

In scala, `object` declaration is used for *singleton objects*.
In this case, `Nil`'s role is of representing 'emptiness' and is used as last parameters of successive `cons`

```lisp
cons(a, Nil) => List(a)
cons(a, cons(b, Nil)) => List(a, b)
```

So why `Nil` is `object` and extends `List`? cause,

- Nil is used as single representation of emptiness of `List`.

We don't need multiple instances of Nil.
It also makes sense that 2nd parameter of `cons` is `List` type.